# How can I return an array of lists with a C# function?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, function

I have the code:

```
List<int>[] DATASET(int[] amounts; int needs; int amount){
    List<int>[] a = new List<int>[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new List<int>();
    }
    return a;
}
```

It's supposed to return an array containing lists in it.
It gives these errors:

```
) expected

; expected

} expected
```

all of that in the first line of the code above, and I can't understand why?

Comment: remove `;` as the delimiter and use `,` in the method arguments

Comment: You're going to get far more benefit by running through some C# tutorials than you will get by asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntactical error.

- Function Parameters are separated by a comma, not with semicolons.

  ```
  //Use comma not a semicolon
  List<int>[] DATASET(int[] amounts, int needs, int amount){ .. }
  ```